# Functions of Random Values - How did they obtain this result?

Tags: probability

Problem: Find the density of $Y = cX$ where $X$ follows a gamma distribution. Show that only $\lambda$ is affected by such a transformation, which justifies calling $\lambda$ a scale parameter.

Solution.

Let $Y = cX$.

Then:

$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{|c|}f_X(\frac{y}{c})$

...(rest of the solution removed)...

How exactly did this happen? I am not sure if I completely understand how they got this result. Could someone show me the intermediate steps achieved here? Did they find the CDF first and then differentiate?

Comment: Think of in terms of CDF first, $P(Y>y)=P(cX>y)=P(X>y/c)$ and now differentiate

Comment: Yeah I got that far. But how do I differentiate P(X > y/c)?

Comment: @MH1993 : Chain rule? $\frac{d}{dy}F_X(y/c) = F'_X(y/c)\cdot\frac1c$

Comment: If you call $F$ a CDF for $X$, then $P(X>y/c)=F(y/c)$ so differentiating with respect to $y$ gets you $\frac{1}{c} f_X(\frac{y}{c})$ but you need it to be positive, so you put that modulus sign around $c$

Comment: Ahhh right. I see. Thank you so much. Does c > 0 because of the inequality?

Comment: Oh, there's a problem with my first comment, it must actually say $P(cX>y)=P(X>y/|c|)$ since $P(cX>y)=P(X>y/c)$ if $c>0$ and inequality is reversed if $c<0$. So correct way is to say $P(X>y/|c|)$

Comment: Yeah I figured as much :) Thank you!